# How to show preview, restrict image type and resize using jQuery file upload plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following jQuery file upload plugin to upload an image.

Plugin URL: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

**Here is my code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
            // $('#fileupload').fileupload('disable');
        }
    });
});
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I restrict image type? Like I want to upload only jpg, png and gif image.
2. How to show preview after upload?
3. How to crop image on the client side or server side?

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ adding this `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,` is not restricting the image type

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ solved it :)